# How can I repair a hole in wood laminate kitchen countertop?

Tags: laminate, table

Builders made a hole in the worktop, the surface is a laminated wood. What is the correct way to repair this ?

[image]

Comment: It's a laminate over particle board, correct?

Comment: Personally, I'd tell the builders that it's their responsibility to get it fixed. That's why they carry insurance... But if I had to do it myself, I think I'd try a dab of dark-colored epoxy. (Darker than the "wood"  generally blends in better than lighter.) Texture wouldn't match, but it would at least seal the surface and make the ding less visible.

Comment: We tried telling him but we noticed this only after he left and got paid he is ignoring us now.

Comment: Pictures of the damage to your house along with details on who did it distributed around town in public places, etc...Chamber of Commerce, Better Business Bureau, anywhere he advertises...

Comment: Damage found after the movers have left is still damage caused by the movers, if you can show that it wasn't there before the movers came through.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "burn-in" or "fill" sticks to repair high pressure laminate as shown in this video.

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Li_i1Vdr7xU

Comment: Might not be as durable as an epoxy-ish solution, not sure how it would do in a moist environment like a kitchen counter, but burn-in *is* the traditional repair method for dings in fine furniture. That gets a +1 from me.